# Use instance method in ActiveRecord where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an instance method that has logic I want to use in a query. My attempts have not worked. I'd rather not duplicate the logic inside is_thing when building my where clause.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def is_thing?
    #... some logic
  end

end
```

I tried

```
Foo.where(is_thing?)
```

and got

> NoMethodError: undefined method `is_thing?' for main:Object

Comment: Try rails `scope`. [Referrence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

Comment: And the way to call instance methods is via object: `Foo.where(Foo.new.is_thing?)`

Answer (score 2):

***The Approach I would recommend***

I do believe that method is not good practice (to chain a where query). It will only add unnecessary complexity.

The better approach is using scope

```
scope :is_thing?, -> { where(thing: true) }
```

and call it

```
Foo.is_thing?.where()
```

***The Why***

The reason it is returned

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_thing?' for main:Object
```

Is because is_thing? is instance variable of Foo

Instance variable can be called on an instance of the class. And not availabe on main object.

You, however could do

```
Foo.where(Foo.new.is_thing?)
```

It is posible to use that if you convert is_thing? to class method. e.g

```
def self.is_thing?
  # code
end
```

and use it this way

```
Foo.where(Foo.is_thing?)
```

Comment: If using a class method, `Foo.where(Foo.is_thing?)` can't be used simply like this: `Foo.is_thing?` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def is_thing?
    #... some logic
  end

  def things
    Foo.where('thing_check = ?', self.is_thing?)
  end

end
```

create another instance method to wrap your `where` query. Then access it as `Foo.last.things`